# Can anyone help me translate the inscription located on the back of my Chinese coin?

Tags: translation, characters

I have not been successful in my search to find another coin with an identical matching inscription. What is the interpretation?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

centre: 光绪元宝 (Guangxu Sycee)

top: 广西省造 (made by province Guangxi)

bottom: 库平七钱二分(26.856gram)

the other scripts on the centre is Manchu, I assume it has the same meaning as 光绪元宝

Comment: Thanks ARCH!  I'M EXTREMELY GRATEFUL.

Comment: @AOD can you accept this answer so this thread can be marked as answered?